# Adding new key/value pair to existing key in chrome.storage.sync

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-storage

I'm new to JSON & Chrome extension development. 
I have two HTML buttons namely 'Start' & 'Stop'. I have following JavaScript code:

```
var storage = chrome.storage.sync;

function setData(key, value) {
    storage.set({ [key]: value });
}

function onClickMarkStartButton() {
    var date = getCurrentDate();
    var start = { 'start': getCurrentTime() };

    setData(date, start);
}

function onClickMarkEndButton() {
    var date = getCurrentDate();
    var end = { 'end': getCurrentTime() };

    setData(date, end);
}
```

It saves

```
6/1/2018 : {
    "start":"16:34"
}
```

OR

```
6/1/2018 : {
    "end":"16:40"
}
```

overwriting the previously saved key/value pair, instead of saving it like this

```
6/1/2018: {
  "start": "16:34",
  "end": "16:40"
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: in `setData` you need to get what's in storage, then modify that structure and write it back.

Comment: @fredrik i just did that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your end function to this:

```
function onClickMarkEndButton() {
    var date = getCurrentDate();
    chrome.storage.sync.get(date, function (obj) {
        setData(date, {
            start: obj.start,
            end: getCurrentTime()
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Worked with some minor modifications. Thanks!

Comment: @Abhishek Glad it did.